# R plotting using a table command - text labels missing

Tags: r, plot

I have code below. Why don't the text labels appear? I want them on top of the each bar.

```
x=c(20,30,70,5,10,20)
aaa=plot(table(x),yaxt='n',main="county", ylab="drop offs")
text(aaa,labels=c(1,2,3,4,5),pos=3,col="red",cex=0.8)
```

Comment: why did the question get downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

Your `text` statement only gives the argument `aaa` to position the text labels. So text is plotting your points at (1,5), (2,10), (3,20), (4,30) and (5,70) - all of which are off the graph and so do not display. You can get almost what you want by changing your `text` statement to:

```
text(aaa, table(x), labels=c(1,2,3,4,5),pos=3,col="red",cex=0.8)
```

But that cuts off the highest label a little,  so I recommend adjusting ylim on the plot.

```
aaa=plot(table(x),yaxt='n',main="county", ylab="drop offs", 
    ylim=c(0,max(table(x)))+0.1)
text(aaa,table(x), labels=c(1,2,3,4,5),pos=3,col="red",cex=0.8)
```

[image: plot with labels]